# Changing encryption scheme utilized in GNU Privacy Guard (GPG)

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I am currently trying to implement my own cryptographic IBE scheme within GPG. I understand that rolling one's own crypto is frowned upon, yet, this is for research purposes only. Is there an easy method of implementation within GPG to add my custom encryption scheme. I've been reading through the source files and it dosen't seem as if there's a clear method to do so. GPGme seems to be more friendly and clear, but still slightly confusing. Any information would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: welcome - i marked this as too broad because i misunderstood your question - if i understand you correctly, you are asking how to implement (any) custom protocol in a modified `gpg`, not how to implement IBE?

Comment: Essentially yes, I am trying to implement my custom protocol within a modified GPG. The custom protocol I have is an IBE scheme. I thought GPG utilized an IBE scheme due to its implementation of emails within key derivation, and custom keys for every individual email.